# jQuery not working in chrome extension popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building my first chrome extension, and I'm having some trouble. I want to use jQuery on popup.html. The popup otherwise works fine, but the jQuery doesn't work.

**Edit:** I changed it, here's the new code, which still doesn't work. Any ideas? I've spent over two hours trying to figure it out. I'm a beginner to extensions and quite rusty in javascript and jquery, so it could definitely be something small and embarrassing... Thanks so much!

**manifest.json**

```
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [website], 
    "js": [
    "content.js", 
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"]
   }],
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>First Google Extension</title>
    <style>
    body { 
        font-family: "Segoe UI"; 
        width: 300px; 
        font-size: 14px; 
        }; 

    #changeMe {
        color: blue; 
        font-style: bold; 
        }; 
    </style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    Welcome to my first Google Chrome Extension! <br> 
    <div id="changeMe">
        I'm different!
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#changeMe").append("Test!");  
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to:

1. Learn to [debug extension popups](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging). It will show you an informative error.
2. Said error will refer to Content Security Policy. So you need to read about [extensions' CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy).
3. After you read the above documentation, the first problem you need to fix is trying to use a remote script. This is [possible](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-remote-script), but for something like jQuery it's best to download a copy of it, add it to extension's folder and include it as a local file:

   ```
   <!-- refers to extension's own folder -->
   <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
   ```
4. Second, you need to collect your own scripts inside a file and include it like that as well; [inline code is not allowed in any form](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution), and content scripts do not apply for extension pages.

Comment: So, it is not possible to load jquery in the manifest for using it in the popup.js?

Comment: @karlihnos The best practice is to include a local copy of the library. Then you can include it in HTML of the popup as usual.

Answer (score 7):

Also make sure to include `jQuery.min.js` before `popup.js`. I made this silly mistake, was loading `popup.js` before `jQuery.min.js` and it doesn't work that way. So always load `jQuery.min.js` first.